# floor instead of ceiling for log2

Tags: binary

A colleague and myself are working out the compression factor for dictionary compressions and we came accross this site, [exploring binary](https://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-bits-in-a-decimal-integer/), in the example of converting base 10 to base 2 numbers it recommends the use of floor instead of ceiling, $$bspec = ⌊\log_2(n)⌋ + 1$$

> To quote the author, "You might be tempted to use the ceiling function — ⌈x⌉, which is the smallest integer greater than or equal to x — to compute the number of bits as such:"
>
> $$bspec = ⌈\log_2(n)⌉$$
>
> However, this fails when n is a power of two.

Could you explain how ceiling fails when n is power of two? And maybe from the perspective of people that are more accustomed to programming not math.

Comment: The number of digits of $2^n$ in binary is $n+1$, a $1$ followed by $n$ zeros. However, $\log_2(2^n)=n$.

Comment: @logarithm:  that should be an answer.

Comment: Yes, please mark as answer. Still trying to get my head around it, however I think I understand :)